# JDBI SQL Annotations how to query CLOB with LIKE

Tags: java, sql, spring, kotlin, jdbi

I'm trying to fetch data from our database using a CLOB column.

Hardcoded strings work:

```
@SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE roles LIKE '%ADMIN%'")
fun findAllByRole(@Bind("role") role: String): List<UserRecord>
```

But when trying using the binder parameter role it doesn't:

```
@SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE roles LIKE %:role%")
@SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE roles LIKE '%:role%'")
@SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE roles LIKE :role")
```

The role parameter contains the string "ADMIN".

What's the correct way to use LIKE on a CLOB with jdbi sql annotations?

Comment: remove colon. for example, `@SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE roles LIKE %role%")`

Comment: Use the last one in your tries and add the `%` as prefix/suffix to the value you pass in.

Answer (score 0):

From a colleague:

```
@SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE roles LIKE CONCAT('%', :role, '%')")
fun findAllByRole(@Bind("role") role: String): List<UserRecord>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by:

```
@SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE roles LIKE :role ")
```

or

```
@SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE roles LIKE CONCAT('%', :role, '%')")
```